# Fire door from indoors (the house) to garage does not fit the jamb properly. Sometimes it's very difficult to close the door as it hits the threshold

Tags: doors, metal, door-frame, threshold, fire-safety

[image: threshold from house to garage.]This old fire door and frame does not fit properly. The metal door sometimes hits the threshold at the bottom and will not close. I have to put shims under the threshold outside to lower the inside of the threshold. This may help the door close. However, also and I have to pull the inside door handle up as hard as I can so it can clear the threshold and close. There are many loose screws and missing screws holding the metal frame into the house frame. I'm not sure who to contact to fix this. This metal door has not fit the frame for a very long time but I have not worried about it until this threshold started interfering with the door.

Comment: Is the door in a metal frame (what might be called the jamb)?  And does the door bolt/screw to the metal frame or do the screws for the hinges from the door go through the frame into the studs?  If it's the later, you may just need longer screws for the top hinge.  In either case, a competent handyman should be able to fix this.

Comment: Pulling up on the handle to close is a sign of a loose top hinge.  If the hinges are tight, should not be able to pull up.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. You'll note that this is a Question & Answer site, but that you've not actually asked us a question. Are you looking to DIY this fix? Then ask how to fix it. If you're looking who to hire, then specifically ask us who to hire. I'm sure you don't want us wasting our time & yours providing answers to questions you didn't really mean to ask...